# How to put into the CSV (text) output of XSL-T 2.0 transformation XML illegal characters like 1E "record separator" and 1F "unit separator"?

Tags: xml, special-characters, xslt-2.0, export-to-csv, saxon

**The question:** 
Is there any way, how to put into the CSV (text) output of XSL-T 2.0 transformation XML illegal characters like 1E "record separator" and 1F "unit separator"? Like

```
 <xsl:text>&#x1F;</xsl:text>
```

**The goal:** 
I would like to transform XML to CSV (to be imported into relational sql database) using XSL-T 2.0 using the latest Java Saxon HE. The CSV result will contain several elements as separate columns and the latest column will contain part of XML (~ DocumentFragment) as CLOB or varchar. The load of data will be huge and permanent (at least 50.000.000 XMLs within 12 hours divided into files per about 2 minutes). XMLs could be about several hundreds of different types ~ XSDs.

**The problem:** 
Because the source XML could contain any valid XML character within Unicode character set, I am facing the problem, how to choose separator of fields (columns) and records (rows) and string delimiter ("string"). To bypass textual replacing and doubling separators and delimiters using (slow?) XSL-T string functions, I would like to use the characters, that could never appear in the source XML. So I can rely on some multicharacter separators and delinmiters (not only one character) or I though about the XML illegal characters into the output, which is single character solution. Moreover I would like to use

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" byte-order-mark="no" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" />
```

because the full XML output into the last column of CSV I would like to create as

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

which sounds like nonsense to create CSV as XML output, but it is very fast for processing and short for coding according to my previus findings.

**Example code** with conventional separators (semicolon and new line) and delimiter (double quote):

*test.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<root>
  <record>
    <elementMetaA>name</elementMetaA>
    <elementMetaB>datetime</elementMetaB>
    <elementBody>
      <anyXml01>
        <anyXml02>myData02</anyXml02>
        <anyXml03>myData03</anyXml03>
      </anyXml01>
    </elementBody>
  </record>
</root>
```

*test.xsl*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet  
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
  version="2.0"> 
  <xsl:output  
    method="xml"  
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"  
    byte-order-mark="no"  
    indent="no"  
    encoding="UTF-8" /> 
  <!-- simple example with  
    newline and semicolon as separators  
    and double quote as string delimiter --> 
  <xsl:template match="/root"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    <xsl:text> 
</xsl:text> 
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="record"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="elementMetaA"> 
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
    <xsl:text>", </xsl:text> 
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="elementMetaB"> 
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
    <xsl:text>", </xsl:text> 
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="elementBody"> 
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
    <xsl:text>" </xsl:text> 
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="text()"/> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank You in advance for Your tips. Stepan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C1 control characters such as x1E and x1F are permitted in XML 1.1 but not in XML 1.0. So first, enable XML 1.1 support in Saxon using -xmlversion:1.1 on the command line (or the equivalent option in the configuration API). Then you have a choice. If the stylesheet is parsed by an XML 1.1 parser you can use `<xsl:text>&#x1f;</xsl:text>`. If not, you can do `<xsl:value-of select="codepoints-to-string(31)"/>`.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank You!
Moreover I have to add `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to the above mentioned solution to get real single character and not XML character reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the fully functional the very easy example of solving my problem is:

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>a</root>
```

**test.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" byte-order-mark="no" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#x1f;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**test.bat**

```
java -jar .\bin\saxon9he.jar -t -s:.\test.xml -xsl:.\test.xsl -o:.\test.txt -xmlversion:1.1
```

**test.txt**

```
!hereIs001F!a
```